# Moving this function into a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I call this function every time I move(click of a button) to the next screen of a wizard or even when I go back to the previous page. It allows me to capture the position of a div. I need to capture it to make a nice sliding transition. It's working really well.

```
function captureContentPosition() {
  var offsets = document.getElementById('content-view').getBoundingClientRect();

  // this code will assign and keep the existing position of the element
  document.getElementById('content-view').style.top = (offsets.top - 65) + 'px';
}
```

Now, I decided to change it into a directive. However, it's not applying the effect. The directive is getting executed.

```
.directive('freezeContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var offsets = element[0].getBoundingClientRect(); // I see value on this code so it's good
      element[0].style.top = (offsets.top - 65) + 'px'; // this one does not do anything
    }
  };
});
```

and on my template

```
<div id="content-view" freeze-content .......></div>
```

of course, I removed the code that calls captureContentPosition() from the function being called by ng-click next/back button.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code everything looks fine. Have you checked the developer console to see whether the element has a style attribute of top? it should. and that doesnt do anything in the DOM, unless the element has an absolute position.

Comment: I got it working. I was just missing a code. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

My directive was fine. I was missing one line. Here is the updated directive.

```
.directive('freezeContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var offsets = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      element[0].style.position = "absolute";
      element[0].style.top = (offsets.top - 65) + 'px';
    }
  };
});
```